# Findbug exclude only works when run on class in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, filter, findbugs

I'm currently using the Findbug Eclipse plugin and a particular bug, when I run FindBugs on the project, keeps showing up, even though it's excluded in the findbugs_exclude.xml file. Then if I run FindBugs on the class containing the bugs, it gets filtered and disappears. If I run FindBugs on the project again, it shows up again. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Findbugs, but the problem remains. Other bug exclusions work properly.

I'm currently using Eclipse Kepler with FindBugs 3. Before reinstalling, FindBugs was at version 3 but was recently updated from FindBugs 2.

I tried filtering that bug using an exclude file, but the result is the same.

Here is the XML filter I use for this particular bug :

```
<Match>
    <Class name="gui.image.overlay" />
    <Method name="rightClicked" params="java.awt.event.MouseEvent,gui.gen.ImageBox" />
    <Bug pattern="HE_USE_OF_UNHASHABLE_CLASS" />
    <Priority value="1" />
</Match>
```

EDIT :

I ran Findbugs again recently and this particular bug wasn't found. Instead, another bug has the same issue. Between these runs of Findbugs, my computer was formatted and everything was reinstalled. Could there be some sort of cache or something that would bypass the findbugs-exclude.xml file?